# C: While loop is not ending even after specifying the end

Tags: c

My problem statement is in such a way that I run a command and save the output of the command in a buffer. My while loop looks for a particular string in the output and if the string exists, runs the required function.

To end the while loop I have mentioned feof, in the while loop but the loop doesn't work!

Here is the snap of the code, I want to end the while loop in an optimized way!

```
FILE *fp = popen("ls","r");
char store[128];

while((fgets(store,sizeof store, fp)!=NULL) || (feof(fp))){
    if(strcasestr(buffer,"abc")){
        printf("\nSuccess");
        some_other_function();
    }
}
pclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Logically, you would put `while (!feof(fp))`. However, that is also wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: That code has logic that might be described as "keep looping so long as we successfully read a line or we're at the end of the file".

Comment: You don't need the `feof()` check. `fgets()` will return `NULL` when you get to EOF.

Comment: @Barmar: More precisely, when it reaches the end of the file. `EOF` is a macro that expands to a negative integer (typically `(-1)`) which is the value returned by certain functions on encountering an end-of-file or error condition.

Comment: @KeithThompson I was using EOF as the generic abbreviation for End-Of-File.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, I know. I suggest not doing that, because `EOF` has a very precise meaning in C.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sorry, it's a very old habit, hard to break. I don't see how "get to EOF" could be confused as comparing something with EOF, especially since I just said the value is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop condition should be:

```
while( fgets(store,sizeof store, fp) != NULL )
```

There is no reason to also check feof at this point. If end of file was reached but some characters were read then you do want to process the string anyway.

You could check `feof` after the loop to determine whether input failed due to a read error, or due to the end of the file.

Answer (score -2):

Replaced the while loop with this, and now it works! Thanks !

```
while((fgets(store,sizeof store, fp)!=NULL) && !(feof(fp)))
```

Comment: ugh - again please see Edward's comments above.

Comment: You still don't need to test `feof(fp)`. `fgets()` performs that test itself.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Edward's comment is only relevant to writing `while (!feof(fp))`. But if you put the `fgets()` call first, it mitigates that problem.

Comment: @Barmar: And `feof(fp)` will never be true if there's an input error. (After `fgets()` reports that it's run out of input, you can *then* call `feof(fp)` and/or `ferror(fp)` to learn more about why it ran out of input.)